# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after executing an asynchronous URL request

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.5

I am trying to execute an asynchronous URL request:

```
    NSURLRequest* request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.youtube.com/"]];
    NSOperation* operation=[NSOperation new];
    NSOperationQueue* queue=[NSOperationQueue new];
    [operation setCompletionBlock: ^()
     {
     }];
    [queue addOperation: operation];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request queue: queue completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[data bytes]);
    }];
```

So I just need the data contained in the URL.But after few seconds (probably in the time that the newly created thread loads the data) the application crashes:

```
thread 6 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address=0x0)
```

The exact point is objc_msgSend_vtable5, in the NSLog line, when I try to print data bytes.
PS: I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the method `-[NSData bytes]` has return type `void *` (and is a pointer to a raw byte buffer), but you're treating the return value as an object by trying to log it using the `%@` [format specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).  To fix this, just print just print `data` rather than `[data bytes]`; replace your line

```
NSLog(@"%@", [data bytes]);
```

with

```
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Comment: Ohh, I didn't understood that bytes was the raw data, I thought it was the length in bytes.Thanks.

Comment: To print the length, use `NSLog(@"%lu", [data length]);`.